# HTML Checkbox validation

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have created check boxes in PHP as follow

```
echo "<Input type = 'Checkbox' class='cl2'  Name =".$i."/>".$f1.
```

Now I want to validate it as a pop up box is created on submit when no check box is checked.

I tried it with the following js

```
function Validate() {
    alert (document.getElementsByClassName('cl2')[0].checked);
    for(i=0;i<=5;i++) {
        if(document.getElementsByClassName('cl2')[i].checked == false) {
            alert("approve atleast one request");
        } else {
            return true;
        } 
    }
}
```

It's not returning anything. What should be the condition in for loop?

Answer (score 2):

you should return false when the validation is invalid, see below.
Watch out when using getElementsByClassName , it's only supported in the newest browsers, you should put in a fallback for older browsers or maybe use jQuery.

```
function Validate() {
    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        if (document.getElementsByClassName('cl2')[i].checked == false) {
            alert("approve atleast one request");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: function validate() 
{
var j =0;
for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('cl2').length; i++) 
{
if (document.getElementsByClassName('cl2')[i].checked)
{
j = 1;    
}
}
if(j!=1)
{
alert("No user has been clicked for submission");
return false;
}
else
return true;
}

Comment: @flyingkandi what are you trying to say ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the length for the for loop try something like:

```
var elem = this.getElementsByTagName('cl2');
for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
```

Comment: getElementsByTagName('cl2') , i'm pretty sure there isn't a "cl2" tag in html.

Comment: 'cl2' is the name of the class he is using for the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to wrap your **name** attribute like this:

```
name='" . $i . "'
```

otherwise, you the **$i** you are concatenating with php will not be wrapped with quotes in your HTML markup when the string gets echoed, and your HTML markup will be erroneous.

Second, I would format the javascript something more like this (not knowing exactly what you're attempting to do)

```
function Validate() {
    var isChecked = false;
    for(i=0; i <= 5; i++) {
        if(document.getElementsByClassName('cl2')[i].checked == true) {
          isChecked = true;
        }
    }
    return isChecked;
}

if(Validate()) {
    // do something 
} else {
    alert("approve atleast one request");   
}
```

Generating return statements inside a loop is bad style, so avoid that. Also, I would try inserting your javascript into a script tag **below** your echoed php, to ensure the script executes after the content loads. Otherwise, you can insert an `onload="Validate()"` attribute in your `<body>` tag, and place the javascript in the `<head>` section of your page.

Hope this helps. Cheers!